# How can you fill a UITableView with data from two arrays of two different object types?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Currently I fill a UITableView using this method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CharNameCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    MyObject *obj = (MyObject*)[self.characters objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = obj.name;

    return cell;
}
```

But what could one do if you had two different arrays from two different types and you wanted to display a property from each in the cells?

Pseudocode:

MyObject1
MyObject2

cellTextLabel.text = Myobject1.name;
cellTextLabel.text = MyObject2.name;

Assuming that each object has a name property. I know my syntax above isn't correct, but I think you should get the drift.

Comment: You should consider creating a protocol, like `MyObjectPresentation` or something. That protocol would have things that get presented like `name` and then all the various classes in the array would implement the protocol.

Comment: Hey Jason - that's a great suggestion. Can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest then that you store all of your objects in an NSMutableArray. This will be your data model. Then you can just iterate through the array to display the data in the UITableView. If need be, use introspection to find out what kind of class your object is.

```
id currentObject = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyObject1 class]]){
    //set properties or do stuff with MyObject1
}else if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyObject2 class]]){
    //do stuff with Object2
}
```

This is just one suggestion. There are many ways to do this, but it will all depend on your app and what kind of persistence you are using, etc. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I meant (thought it may not have been clear) that I'd like each object to appear in its own cell. That won't work for that. :(

Comment: @Darkenor How many objects do you have and in what order do you want them

Comment: There are currently two, but it may be as many as 20 ultimately. I want the object's name property to display in a UITableView and then, upon selection, drill down to further details of the object in another view.

Comment: @Darkenor I would suggest then that you store your objects in an NSMutableArray. This will be your data model. Then you can just iterate through the array to display the data in the UITableView. If need be, use introspection to find out what kind of class your object is.